# What is this learning approach called?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I'm doing time-series forecasting by quantizing the change vector $\Delta$ where $\Delta_{i} = x_{i} - x_{i-1}$ let's say into 5 bins, so that the output (a discrete vector) has 1 = big drop, 2 = small drop, 3 = small/no change, 4 = small rise, 5 = big rise, and I'm doing 5-class classification given the past values of the output (autoregressive and seasonal terms) and the input variables. And I'm simply measuring the prior and transition probabilities by looking at the past data.

Is this called a naive Bayes classifier? Also how do I make an HMM for this approach? Do I need a hidden variable for an HMM? Finally, how is such an approach used in current context, i.e. what is the state of the art for this, I'm looking directions to improve my work, so any advice on this would be appreciated.

Thanks,